Qt Visual Studio Tools update causes a linker error
The code in my codebase has been compiling for years. I just upgraded Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 to version 16.11.41 and now when building my Visual Studio solution I get:
qtmaind.lib(qtmain_win.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function _WinMain@16
The offending project is for the main application, which is a managed C++ CWinApp-based application. As described in the Microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/cwinapp-the-application-class?view=msvc-170) -

Like any program for the Windows operating system, your framework application has a WinMain function. In a framework application, however, you do not write WinMain. It is supplied by the class library and is called when the application starts up.

I saw another old post that referenced this issue, Windows unicode commandline argv, but the discussion there seemed to be revolving around the correct form of main to use for a Unicode application. Unfortunately, my understanding of CWinApp applications leads me to believe I do not have access to main.
Any ideas?  My assumption here is that this is a Microsoft problem related to the new version of Visual Studio, and I'm interested to know if anyone has encountered anything similar.

Some code would help, for example what does your main function look like (or do you have one). Also some idea of the settings and structure of your project, so please give a little detail on that kind of thing.

I assume this is Qt5? What build system are you using, e.g. qmake, cmake or something else? Depending on the answer to that question, what does your *.pro or CMakeLists.txt contain?

@john - Sorry, I assumed people would understand that CWinApp-based applications don't have an accessible main - from the documentation "In a framework application, however, you do not write WinMain."

@ChristianHalaszovich - It is Qt 5.13.2 in a Visual Studio solution. As for including code - the offending project is just a CLR project that is dependent on about 190 other projects consisting of static libraries and dlls.

That looks just like after vs tools update it refers to wrong platform version of qt install (you're likely have several). Might be a bug, might be related to fact that Qt5  lifetime is ended and new variants of qt6 again are changing directory structure - similar breakage happened with upgrade from qt4 to qt5.

Mystery solved - turns out it was a Qt VS Tools update (from 3.2.0.47 to 3.3.0.13) that did it. Rolling back to an earlier version seems to fix the problem.
Here is the Qt bug report: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTVSADDINBUG-1242

I have the same issue even in version 3.2.0.47.
I have multiple Qt projects some working without problem and one of them have this issue. My VS solution has multiple static lib projects and the qt application.

@CemPolat - Not sure what could be going on there. What I do see is the plugin is very adamant about updating. When I get the errors again, I check and find that the plugin has updated. That is, even when the auto-update is unchecked, it still sneaks in. At my site, we have found that we had to disconnect from network, downgrade to 3.2.0.47, select do not update, and then reconnect to the network.

I guess my case could be related with opening multiple solutions that have QT Projects. I often use multiple instances of Visual Studio IDE to debug server-client like applications. Thus, multiple instances of QT VS Tools works simultaneously that seems to cause trouble especially QT project settings are different.
I could restore after cleaning all projects, deleting all .vs files and restart both IDEs.
